# Notepad++ Regex: Find all lines with UPPERCASE names, words, or tokens

Tags: regex, notepad++, regex-lookarounds, pcre, regex-negation

I'm trying to find a regex that will identify all lines in a text file with only CAPITAL / UPPERCASE letters. To clarify, **it can have other types of characters (period, space, hyphen, etc.), but the line should only match if there are 4 or more UPPERCASE letters and zero lowercase letters.**

I have tried various approaches including negative character classes and negative / positive lookaheads (copied from other SO posts), but none worked. Here is the one I came up with that seemed like it should have worked, and in fact, worked *somewhat* in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/7bjsp):

`[A-Z]{2,}`

[*I realize that 2 should be a 4, but the results are basically the same for my purposes*]

Here is a screenshot of what is matched in RegExr:

[image: screen-regexr--error--find-uppercase-lines-01]

But, as you can see here and in NotePad++ it is finding each name `token` individually, but I want the entire line to matched. In the screenshot below, "DONNA" is matched, then "RIGNEY", but it needs to match `"DONNA RIGNEY"`.

[image: screen-regexr--error--find-uppercase-lines-02]

---

Answer (score 1):

```
^               # Match a full line
(?!.*[a-z])     # if it does not contain any lower case letter and if it contains
.*?             # 0+ characters, followed by
(?:[A-Z].*){4}  # 4 groups, each consists of an uppercase letter and 0+ more characters
$               # right before the end of line.
```

Options:

- ☑ Match case
- ☐ `.` matches newline <sub>[sic]</sub>

Try it [on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bBBxJc/1).

## Further explanation

By observation, we can see that all lines that have 4 or more uppercase letters follow this pattern:

```
<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>...
```

Since `<anything>` can also contains uppercase letters, it can be minified as:

```
<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>[A-Z]<anything>
```

There are 4 `[A-Z]<anything>`, so we can collapse them to:

```
<anything>([A-Z]<anything>){4 times}
```

This can be translated into regex as:

```
.*(?:[A-Z].*){4}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this pattern: `^([^a-z\n]*[A-Z]){4,}([^a-z\n])*$`

The first group `([^a-z\n]*[A-Z]){4,}` is for matching group of UPPERCASE and all other letters except lowercase, and should repeat at lease 4 times.

The second group `([^a-z\n])*` is for matching all letters except lowercase at the end of line.

See demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/O1tl4B/1)